# How to set Apache'config to make sure every website just has one process?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I have one vps of Linux System with three websites upon it.
The Apache will generates a new process to handle a new request,but it's not easy for me to calculate the cpu usage of single website because I need to sum every process.
So,the question,How to set Apache'config to make sure every website just has one process?

Answer (score 0):

That's how Apache works. If you limit a website to just one process, then you'd only be able to handle one request.

Like you said, Apache generates one process per request.

If you'd like a different behavior I suggest nginx, which utilizes only a single worker process.

If you'd like to continue using Apache, perhaps you just need to change how you do your monitoring.